# How to add new row data to PowerBi table on refresh

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, google-cloud-dataflow, power-automate

On our SQL Server, our org has a table that contains a current instance of records. I need to query that table and append the output row(s) to a PowerBi data table.

I have researched doing this in Power Automate with the “Add Rows to a dataset” step. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to use the aforementioned SQL query as the payload.

Has anyone else encountered this use case? Is there an alternative way to continuously add rows to a table based on a SQL query?

Comment: Could you use a view to wrap both sources of data in a view and make the view your source for PowerBI?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with this stock template:

https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/details/ab50f2c1faa44e149265e45f72575a61/add-sql-server-table-rows-to-power-bi-data-set-on-a-recurring-basis/

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways

1. Incremental refresh https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview
2. Duplicate's remover, you download whole DB, and then remove dublicates
3. Crete SQL side VIEW which do same things, and in PBI side use this VIEW